# How to parse string XML and extract int values

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

What would be the simple way of parsing XML below which is of string datatype and get the IDs as array of int. Using C#.Net

```
   <IDs>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <ID>4</ID>
  </IDs>
```

Comment: What had you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, and for this simple case most of them would be as simple. For example using [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) we can query `<ID>` using LINQ or XPath :

```cs
var xml = @"<IDs>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <ID>4</ID>
  </IDs>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var idsFromLinq = doc.Root
                     .Elements("ID")
                     .Select(o => (int)o)
                     .ToList();
var idsFromXPath = doc.XPathSelectElements("/IDs/ID")
                      .Select(o => (int)o)
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks har07. I was using XDocument but I was using XDocument.Load()which doesn't take string. and I don't want create System.IO classes. I didn't see Parse() method is there.

Answer (score -2):

You can use XmlDocument type:

```
        string _xml = "<IDs><ID>1</ID><ID>2</ID><ID>3</ID><ID>4</ID></IDs>";

        XmlTextReader _xtr = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(_xml));
        _xtr.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.Significant;

        XmlDocument _xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        _xdoc.Load(_xtr);

        XmlElement root = _xdoc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/IDs/ID");

        int[] _ids = new int[4];
        int i = 0;

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
        {
            _ids[i] = Convert.ToInt32(node.InnerText);
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: -1 for using `new XmlTextReader` instead of `XmlReader.Create`, for not putting the `XmlReader` into a `using` block, and for posting a solution using `XmlReader` when the OP clearly asked about LINQ to XML.